# Get a particular object from an arrayList of different objects

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, interface, drag-and-drop

I have an interface MyShape, and I have 3 classes, MyLine, MyEllipse, and MyRectangle.

I have an ArrayList of MyShape that fills up as you draw a particular shape to the screen.

When you right click on a shape you should be able to drag it around the screen. I want to call the contains method on the shape that is right clicked to see if the event coordinates fall within.

I want to do something around the lines of,

```
for(int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++){
    if(shapes.get(i).contains(e.getX(),e.getY()){
        shapes.get(i).move(e.getX(),e.getY()){
    }
}
```

However the shapes interface doesnt extend anything so it doesn't have access to the contains method. I've tried adding the contains method to the interface, and  then overriding it by calling the super class method in each shape class but that didn't work either.

To sum up my question. How can I call the contains method on a list of the MyShape interface. Or a subquestion, how can I get the particular class at index i, and call the contains method on that particular class.

Comment: When you tried to add `contains()` to `MyShape` how did you override it? What was the code you wrote. Because that seems like you had the right idea, but the `contains()` method didn't work in the MyLine, MyEllipse and MyRectangle

Comment: When you said "'ve tried adding the contains method to the interface, and then overriding it by calling the super class method in each shape class but that didn't work either." why did it not work, what error did you face?

Comment: I tried calling super(); which didn't work. I tried calling this.contains(), which did work I think, and but it game me a stack overflow exception I believe.

I believe I also tried Ellipse2D.contains() as well

Comment: When you create the `contains()` method in the `MyShape` you will then need to actually implement the functionality that on your `MyRectangle`, e.g. `if(x and y inside all 4 corners)` So inside you actual shapes you will have the method that is the in the interface, but full implemented, with the logic to figure it out, because obviously, finding out how an Ellipse contains something is a lot different to a rectangle.

Comment: So in side `MyShape` you will have something like `public boolean contains(int x, int y);` and in your other shapes, `public boolean contains(int x, int y){ //code to figure out if it contains}`